# DecodeByteArray with WebService image always null

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image

There what I am trying to do :

I am calling a WebService that send me back an image.
I get it from the `entity.getContent()` method.

Further in my code I try to use de `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myImage, 0, myImage.lenght)` but the Bitmap that it returns me is always `null`

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

decodeByteArray returns null when the image cannot be decoded from that array, you are probably getting the image in a format that BitmapFactory doesnt understand.